# volatile for variable that is only read in ISR?

Tags: c, interrupt, volatile

Is `volatile` needed for a variable that is read&write in main loop, but read-only in ISR?

EDIT:  At the moment of writing in main, the ISR is disabled. So, the variable is effectively used atomically.

**EDIT:** (Very much related):

[volatile vs memory barrier for interrupts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56791401/6872717)

Comment: Volatile tells the compiler not to optimize away reads and writes, so it may be needed depending on the code.

Comment: What controls the ISR?

Comment: I disable the interrupt by writing a `0` to the corresponding register (`TXIE`), write to the variable (the one of the question)(a buffer for UART data), and then enable the interrupt again & start the transmission. After transmitting each character from the buffer, the hardware will fire the ISR (ISR code is written by me) which loads the next character from the buffer to the TX register, until the buffer is completely used.  At that point, the code in the ISR will disable the interrupt again by writing to the register.

Comment: You should consider using atomics operations, which have a memory order parameter, unlike volatile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`volatile` is a bad way to synchronize access.  It is an optimization barrier but not more.

- it is not atomic; e.g. when your `some_type` is `uint64_t` on a platform without native 64 bit datatypes, there might be read only a part.  E.g.

  ```
  main()                  irq()

  /* initialization */ 
  var[0..31]  = 4
  var[32..63] = 8

  /* modificatoin */ 
  var[32..63] = 23
                        /* read */
                        a_hi = var[32..64] = 32
                        a_lo = var[0..31]  = 4
  var[0..31] = 42
  ```
- depending on architecture, there might be needed memory barrier operations.  E.g. when `main` and `irq` runs on different cores which have dedicated caches, the `irq` will never see the updated value

The first problem requires locking but locking operations usually imply an optimization barrier, so that `volatile` is superfluously.

Ditto for the second problem where memory barriers act as an optimization barrier too.

`volatile` is useful for implementing access to processor memory (which might change between two reads or have side effects when writing).  But usually, it is unneeded and too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

> Is volatile needed for a variable that is read&write in main loop, but read-only in ISR?

`volatile` is not the issue here, as much as insuring `main` loop's writes are not broken apart.

Any changes in `main()` without protection from an ISR call, can lead to problems, `volatile` or not.  Declaring it `volatile` does not save code from that issue.

```
volatile some_type obj;

void ISR() {
  foo(obj);
}

int main() {
  for (;;) {
    // volatile useful here to prevent the assignment from being optimized away.
    some_type tmp = bar();

    // protect from potential interruption need here.

    // Without protection, ISR(), 
    // doesn't know it is working with a completely written `obj`
    obj = tmp;

    // release from potential interruption
}
```

`volatile` is useful in both directions, for `main()` to know `ISR()` may have changed `obj` and for `main()` to not optimize away assignments.

<strike>Yet since `ISR()` does not change `obj`, so `volatile`  is not needed.</strike>

Declaring `obj` `atomic` may help - but that is another question.

Comment: I've been rethinking about it, and... Wouldn't the compiler be allowed to remove some writes to the variable in the main loop if it thinks it isn't being used?  And then the ISR would find an invalid value for the variable.  That would be prevented by `volatile`, right?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Yes code like `int x; x = 1; x = 0;` could omit the `x = 1;` unlike `volatile int y; y = 1; y = 0;`.  Still the write needs to be done atomically, potentially needing a block on a potential `ISR()` interrupt. `volatile int z; block(); z = 1; unblock(); foo(); block(); z = 0; unblock();`.  See also `atomic`.