# C string standard library, memset and discarded volatile keyword

Tags: c, volatile, xc32

I'm getting warning like this on xc32 compiler (gcc based microcontroller compiler, not open-source).

> modem_uart.c:66:5: warning: passing argument 1 of 'memset' discards
> 'volatile' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]

Here is the code:

```
#include <string.h>
// (...)
volatile char rxbuf[MODEM_UART_RXBUF_SIZE];
// (...)

void some_function(void)
{    
    // (...)
    memset(rxbuf, 0, MODEM_UART_RXBUF_SIZE); // <- warning here
    // (...)
}
```

Can someone explain why compiler is discarding volatile?

Comment: Because the declaration of `memset()` doesn't have `volatile` on the first argument.

Comment: Library function did not discard `volatile`, this code attempts to discard `volatile` with the call and the compiler wisely warns.

Comment: @FredLarson Yes, actually this is very similar to what I'm doing. Thanks for link that explains also my other concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification in the standard of [`memset`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.6.1) has the following declaration:

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

The first argument is not declared `volatile void *s`. So it doesn't guarantee to obey the extra restrictions on accessing `volatile` data. Making every call to `memset()` treat the destination as if were volatile would impose an unnecessary performance impact.

If you need those assurances, you should replace the `memset()` call with an explicit loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MODEM_UART_RXBUF_SIZE; i++) {
    rxbuf[i] = 0;
}
```

If you need this from multiple places in your code, you could put it into a `volatile_memset()` function.

Comment: Can I add `register` modifier for `i` inside `for` to make it faster? Well, that could be a subject for another question...

Comment: That's practically never needed. Compilers are good at figuring out which variables would get the most benefit from being in registers.

Comment: @Kamil How could forcing the compiler to do something that it already can do if it's the fastest option possibly make your code any faster?

Comment: @Kamil In general, the `register` modifier is considered obsolete. It was useful years ago when optimizers weren't as clever as they are now.

Comment: @Barmar Well, this is microcontroller compiler, I don't know on which gcc version is it based on, there is probably custom optimizer code (not written by crowd, probably few guys in Microchip)... Maybe I will check that it in the disassembler window.

Answer (score 1):

Your platform doesn't provide a `memset` function that is guaranteed to respect whatever guarantees it provides for `volatile`. So, in order to call `memset`, the compiler must discard the `volatile` qualifier on `rxbuf`.

You should probably write your own implementation of `memset` that respects whatever guarantees you expect `volatile` to provide for you. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54965696/721269) includes one for `memcpy` to solve a similar problem. If there are no such guarantees, then get rid of `volatile`.